# Overriding Ruby's & and | methods doesn't require . operator?

Tags: ruby

When I override an existing method e.g.

```
def add(a, b)
  a - b
end
```

I still have to call that method using the . operator: `some_instance.add(3,2)`

However, if I override the `&` or `|` operators e.g.

```
  def &(other)
    And.new(self, other)
  end
```

then I don't have to use the . operator and can instead do:

```
some_instance & some_other_instance
```

Why is `&` and `|` overriding special, not requiring me to do something like:

```
some_instance.&(some_other_instance)
```

Comment: In C++ that's called "Koenig Lookup". You don't need to fully qualify overloaded operators to call them...

Comment: Operators are just method calls in disguise, `a  & b` is a different way of writing `a.&(b)` so operators override exactly the same as other methods. The overriding isn't special, operators in general are special.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Ruby is simply saying that methods having certain names can optionally be written in a particular shorthand form. In particular, for methods with those names that take a single argument the method name can be placed between the receiver and the argument (`1 + 2`). Note that the rule applies to the name of the method, not to specific methods having those names (e.g., `Array#+`). For example, `class C; def &(other) 'cat' end; end; c1 = C.new; c2 = C.new; c1 & c2
 #=> "cat"`.

Comment: @Darkisa in your method, did you notice that you wrote `a - b` instead of `a.-(b)`? ;-)